# Pass PowerShell parameter values from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, powershell

Basically I need to pass result from a JavaScript to a PowerShell.

I have a Power Shell script that opens IE, fill all data and submit the the form. JavaScript returns the correct value, and now I need to pass back to PowerShell the result.

**PowerShell Script (invoke_cardtoken.ps1):**

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
$cardname="Carlos"
$cardnumber="5555555555554444"
$cardsecuritycode="123"
$cardexmonth="12"
$cardexyear="2020"
$ie.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/Admin/invoke_cardtoken.html")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
$cardnamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('namein')
$cardnamefield.value = "$cardname"
$cardnumberfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('numberin')
$cardnumberfield.value = "$cardnumber"
$cardsecuritycodefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('cvcin')
$cardsecuritycodefield.value = "$cardsecuritycode"
$cardexmonthfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('exmonthin')
$cardexmonthfield.value = "$cardexmonth"
$cardexyearfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('exyearin')
$cardexyearfield.value = "$cardexyear"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('submitin')
$Link.click()
```

**HTML With JavaScript (invoke_cardtoken.html):**

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <script src="https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="paymentForm" method="post">
         <span id="paymentErrors"></span>
         <div class="form-row">
            <label>Name on Card</label>
            <input data-worldpay="name" name="name" type="text" id="namein"/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row">
            <label>Card Number</label>
            <input data-worldpay="number" size="20" type="text" id="numberin"/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row">
            <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
            <input data-worldpay="exp-month" size="2" type="text" id="exmonthin"/>
            <label> / </label>
            <input data-worldpay="exp-year" size="4" type="text" id="exyearin" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-row">
            <label>CVC</label>
            <input data-worldpay="cvc" size="4" type="text" id="cvcin" />
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Place Order" id="submitin"  onclick='pipePass()'/>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var form = document.getElementById('paymentForm');
         Worldpay.useOwnForm({
           'clientKey': 'xxxx',
           'form': form,
           'reusable': false,
           'callback': function(status, response) {
             document.getElementById('paymentErrors').innerHTML = '';
             if (response.error) {               Worldpay.handleError(form, document.getElementById('paymentErrors'), response.error); 
             } else {
               var token = response.token;
         alert(token);
               Worldpay.formBuilder(form, 'input', 'hidden', 'token', token);
               form.submit();
             }
           }
         });
      </script>`enter code here`
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier and cleaner to call the API of the payment processing service directly with Powershell, using `Invoke-Webrequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod`. Get the token from the response with `ConvertFrom-JSON`, and then proceed in Powershell.